# Why auto generated Factories do not extends or implements any classes (interfaces)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, di, factory

This is more abstract question then specific problem.

**Why auto-generated factories in magento do not implements any common interface?**

And what bothers me maybe more. **Why auto-generated factories doesn't extend each other**, so they could be properly passed as arguments.

---

For example. I have `class MagicClass`.
Then I make a class `class MoreMagicClass extends MagicClass`.

By my opinion auto-generated `MoreMagicClassFactory` should extend `MagicClassFactory`.

So when i have another class with constructor that looks like this `__construct(MagicClassFactory $magicClassFactory)`, I could pass the childs factory as well.

I would like to make that as a feature request, but I suspects, there is a good reason, why the auto-generated factories does not behave the way i would like to.

So, is there a reason?

---

### EDIT:

I made feature request on Magento official forum.

- [Factories should extend each other](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Auto-generated-factories-should-extend-each-other/idi-p/63464#M2730)
- [Factories should implementcommon interface](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Autogenerated-Factories-should-implement-common-interface/idi-p/63463#M2729)

Comment: I like your idea, @michal.hosna, such generators functionality is definitely achievable, probably it can be a feature request https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/idb-p/feature-requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to Marius answer when you look at those auto-generated factories code it is always only call of `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface::create()`. There is no more to it. Making it extend each other to some abstract factory would mean that those auto-generated classes would be completely empty or having one property with class name to instantiate.

You can also look at the code that currently generates Factory classes, it's in `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Factory`. Adding parent classes there would require some additional complications as you would either have to generate them recursively which can be dangerous as php can have xdebug with max nesting level set. If not recursively then you would generate code for class ChildFactory and when try to load it went again to code generator to generate code for ParentFactory and so one. Since magento classes tend to have large ancestry line I suspect this process would extend di:compile noticable. In production mode this would be only done once in a while when you update the server but in development when you work on the code and do have to regenerate those classes frequently it could be pain in the ass to already slow system.

All in all applying inheritance to auto-generated factories would have not much benefit with significant larger costs of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reasons for the factories of related classes to be related by themselves.
A factory has only one scope. Create other instances.
`MagicClassFactory` creates instances of `MagicClass` and `MoreMagicClassFactory` creates instances of `MoreMagicClass`.
They should not know more about the classes they instantiate. They should not care if the classes are related somehow.

For implementing an interface, I'm not sure about it. Maybe it makes sense for all of them to implement a `FactoryInterface` or something like that. I have no definitive answer/opinion on this.

But in addition, if you don't like for some reason the autogenerated factory, you can build your own as it fits your needs.
The factories are autogenerated only if the class does not exist.
So if you have the class `MagicClassFactory` written by you, Magento will not autogenerate one in `var/generation`.

Comment: "...you can build your own as it fits your needs." Yes, i know that, but i don't thinks it's good doing so, only to solve this problem.

Comment: If you need it for a specific case, it makes sense. Otherwise I don't see why the factories should know anything about each other. Maybe the interface implementation. You might be right there.

Comment: But i still don't se why factories should not know about each other. Why should factories be that dumb. Does it break some design pattern, some norm?